# Delete Old Outlook Appointments

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

I was working on a way to programmatic delete old outlook calendar appointments.  I have this code, but I am getting a compile error of 'Invalid Expression Term ')' but it looks A-Okay to me?  It's the foreach line that is giving me the trouble.

```
    string strCurrent;
Outlook.Application objApp;
Outlook.NameSpace objNS;
Outlook.MAPIFolder objFolder;
Outlook.Items objItems;
object objItem;
string strStart;
string strEnd;
string strFilter;

strStart = "04/01/2014";
strEnd = "04/28/2014";

strFilter = "[Start] >= " + strStart + " AND [Start] < " + strEnd;
objApp = new Outlook.Application();
objNS = objApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
objFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar);
objItems = objFolder.Items.Restrict(strFilter);
objItem = objItems.GetFirst;
if (objItem = null) { break; }
foreach (object objItem in Outlook.Items objItems) { objItem.Delete; }
objApp = null;
objNS = null;
objFolder = null;
objItems = null;
objItem = null;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for `foreach` is

```
foreach(TYPE item in collection)
{
}
```

Whereas you have currently

```
foreach(TYPE item in ANOTHER_TYPE collection)
{
}
```

So you need something like

```
foreach (var item in objItems)
{
}
```

Comment: Looks like I am going to have to do a major revamp of my coding as I am unable to change the type of objItem since it is declared in my code a few lines up.

Comment: I saw that, so changed my suggestion to name the loop variable as just `item`.

Answer (score 1):

the `foreach` is not in the correct format.
you wrote:

```
foreach (object objItem in Outlook.Items objItems) { objItem.Delete; }
```

it should be:

```
foreach (object objItem in objItems) { objItem.Delete; }
```

other than that there is a `break` in a context where it is not expected:

```
if (objItem = null) { break; }
```

also i suggest a cycle with a backward counter instead of a foreach; when you delete an item the collection is changed and that will create issues at runtime.

Comment: @Bolu you are right, the compiler (and VS2010 IDE also) will warn and stop you. missed that :-/